# The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received function log

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to remove error

```
const fs = require('fs');
function MathTable(n) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 12; ++i) {
        console.log(n + " * " + i + " = " + n * i)
        result = (console.log);
     }
     return result;
}

let a = MathTable(10);
console.log(a); 

NodeJSWriteFile('filename',a);
```

Error : The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received function log

Comment: You are using console.log which is for logging. Save those values in a variable and add that to result.

Comment: Recommend you to read what are variables, how to use them etc. in javascript